# Invariant differential form and compact Lie group actions

Tags: lie-groups, differential-forms, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on a manifold $M$.  Denote the action by $\tau_g(p):=g\cdot p$.  Let $dg=\nu$ be a left invariant volume form on $G$ such that $\int_G \nu =1$.  Let $\alpha$ be a $k$-form on $M$.  To simplify things, take $k=1$. Define
$$
\widehat{\alpha} = \int_G [\tau_{g}^\ast \alpha]dg.
$$
Concretely, for $X\in T_pM$, $\widehat{\alpha}_p(X)$ is defined by
$$
\widehat{\alpha}_p(X)=\int_G \alpha_{g\cdot p}((\tau_g)_\ast X) dg.
$$
How does one show that this is actually $G$-invariant? Let $f_{X,p}: G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the real valued smooth function on $G$ given by
$$
f_{X,p}(g):=\alpha_{g\cdot p}((\tau_g)_\ast X).
$$
Then we can rewrite $\widehat{\alpha}_p(X)$ as
$$
\widehat{\alpha}_p(X) = \int_G f_{X,p}\nu
$$
so that we're just integrating a real valued function on $G$ over $G$.  $G$-invariance of $\widehat{\alpha}$ means
$$
(\tau_h^\ast\widehat{\alpha})_p(X) =\widehat{\alpha}_{h\cdot p}((\tau_h)_\ast X)=\widehat{\alpha}_p(X).
$$
To rephrase the question, how does one show
$$
\int_G f_{(\tau_h)_\ast X,h\cdot p}\nu = \int_G f_{X,p}\nu?
$$
The functions $f_{(\tau_h)_\ast X,h\cdot p}$ and $f_{X,p}$ are related by
$$
(R_h)^\ast f_{X,p}= f_{(\tau_h)_\ast X,h\cdot p}
$$
where $R_h:G \rightarrow G$ is **right** translation by $h\in G$.  If $f_{(\tau_h)_\ast X,h\cdot p}$ and $f_{X,p}$ were related by a left translation, then we would be done, since we can use the fact that $L_h^\ast \nu =\nu$ and the fact that integrals are invariant under orientation preserving diffeomorphisms.  The way to fix the problem is to define
$$
\widehat{\alpha} = \int_G [\tau_{g^{-1}}^\ast \alpha]dg.
$$
In other words use the pullback by $\tau_{g^{-1}}$ not $\tau_g$.  However, no one seems to do this which suggests that I'm making a mistake somewhere.  Can someone point out where my reasoning is incorrect?

Comment: I think the key point here is that compact Lie groups are *unimodular*, i.e. the Haar measure *dg* is bi-invariant (and thus invariant under the inversion map).

Comment: I think you are right.  For a connected compact Lie group $G$, $dg$ is both left and right invariant and this solves the problem.  However, $dg=\nu$ is not necessarily preserved by the inversion map $\iota: G\rightarrow G$, $g\mapsto g^{-1}$.  All we can say is $\iota^\ast \nu =\pm \nu$.  In fact, $\iota^\ast \nu =\nu$ iff $\dim G$ is even (where $G$ is connected and compact).

Comment: Are you interpreting $dg$ here as a measure or a differential form? As you point out, the formula is false in the latter case due to orientation issues.

Comment: I take $dg$ to be a left invariant volume form satisfying $\int_G dg = 1$.